# What year was the second temple destroyed?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash

What year, in the equivalent Gregorian, and Hebrew, was the second temple destroyed?

Edit: I did some googling before posting and it seems that there's a discrepancy between chazal and the secular historians.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70) This question doesn't show much research effort...

Comment: The (insignificant) discrepancy you mention is based on the *Book of Daniel*, whose prophetic vision of the seventy weeks (9:24-27) takes place in the first year of Darius (9:1-2), which can be shown (11:1-4) to be the same as [Darius II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_II), whose reign started in 423 BCE. Since there is no year zero, by adding precisely 490 years, we get 68 CE.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually three different years found in Jewish sources for the destruction of the second Holy Temple in Jerusalem:

3828 / 68 CE

3829 / 69 CE

3830 / 70 CE

This discrepancy is based on a number of factors. For more on that see:
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2641925/jewish/Which-Year-Was-the-Second-Temple-Destroyed-69-CE-or-70-CE.htm

Comment: So I guess we can now figure out which opinion was right

Comment: It would be great to add a short summary to the answer besides the link.